# Applying Themeroller to dynamically created items

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a jQuery Mobile template which later is going to be deployed as an Android app using phonegap/cordova. This template interacts with database through a web-service.

The theme for this app is custom one, downloaded from JQM's "themeroller". Now I have a javascript file (**scripts.js** referred in my HTML's `<head>` section) as follows -

```
function GetBprList1() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://192.168.0.101:80/DRLServiceHost/BPRService.svc/AllBPRS",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:"json", 
    success:  function (msg) {
      var BPRList = '';
      BPRList += '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">'
      $.each(msg, function(i,v){      
        BPRList += '<li><a href="#bprPage" data-transition="slide"><p class="title">' + v.BPRNo + '</p><p class="bodyEle">' + v.BPR_Product +'</p><p class="bodyEle">' + v.BPR_Details+ '</p><br/><p class="bodyEle">' + v.BPR_Status + ':</p></a></li>'      
      })
      BPRList += '</ul>' // Sending my dynamic <ul> to BPRListTable <div>
      $("#BPRListTable").html(BPRList) ;      
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("error");
    }
   });
 };
```

Here all my data using GET is working and a `<ul>` is being created with the `<li>`s as per the function.

But my Jquerymobile theme is not being applied to this dynamically added `<ul>` and its `<li>`'s

Can anyone help me why this is a problem? Is it not possible to apply JQM's theme to a dynamically added HTML tag?

Comment: the listview isn't styled at all? if so, after `error: function` add this `$('[data-role=listview]')listview().listview('refresh')`.

Comment: mm.. makes sense. Will try now.. but even when I refresh page manually, the styling won't appear...

Comment: Another note add `<ul data-role=listview>` directly to `#BPRListTable` and then dynamicaly append `<li>` to it.

Comment: @Omar - adding <ul data-role="listview> directly to BPRListTable worked...

Comment: @Omar.. can we do it for a <table> also, similar to a listview?

Comment: like.. $('[data-role=table]')table().table('refresh') - did not work for me... it showed up only one row out of 10 rows in my table